# drop and drag outlook email and parse lt into MS SQLdatabase

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I am developing a web application that must allow a user to drag and drop an email message from outlook into something similar to a drag and drop upload file component. My application must then take the email and parse it into the MSSQL database.

I have been looking around for answers and found this thread:
[Drag and Drop directly from Outlook to a webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792929/drag-and-drop-directly-from-outlook-to-a-webform)

The thread is half not helping as a drag and drop component dont seem to accept a email message. Can anyone help me with the parsing problem as well? I am using c# asp.net with mssql.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C) using the `IDataObject` interface

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja. I had a look at this and I can see where you are coming from but, I think I found the issue for the file not uploading. I still need a simple solution to parse an outlook message. Remember I am using asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with Outlook and drag-n-drop to a browser [is that Outlook is a bit lazy and only provides drag data in `text/plain` mimetype format](http://codebits.glennjones.net/dragdrop/contenteditable.htm).

The only way you can support drag-n-drop from Outlook to ASP.NET is using a plugin (*ActiveX, Silverlight, or Flash*). Other alternatives would be to use a thick client (*WPF, WinForms, etc.*) which supports native drag-n-drop or building an Outlook Addin that allows uploading directly to your web application or data store.

See [this related SO post regarding drag-n-drop from Outlook to a web form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2200926/175679).